# deny files without extension with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

my server was hacked and somebody placed files without a file extension. 
how can I deny access to those files with .htaccess?

and does it even make sense?

Comment: If you know they are present, why not just delete them instead of attempting to deny access? Or better, restore a backup?

Answer (score 3):

> does it even make sense?

No. First, you need to figure out how your server was hacked, and fix that. Second, if you have all these files being served from within your document root you need to remove them. If it's a matter of you not knowing what's been changed, then you need to revert to a backup, or go through file per file your entire site and purge the files that don't belong there and check the files that should be there that they've not been modified.

But if you still want to try to use rewrite rules, for the sake of the exercise, to prevent access to files without an extension, you'd want something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (^|/)([^/.]+)$ - [L,F]
```

Note that if your server got hacked, they can easily change your htaccess file.